# Finding the median of a set of pictures using PIL and NumPy gives a black and white image

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to combine a set of images by converting them into NumPy arrays and finding the element-wise median of the arrays, resulting in one array. I then convert this array back to an image.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
images_matrices = []

for photo in get_photos(): #just gets a list of photo filenames
    image_matrix = np.array(open_image(photo))
    images_matrices.append(image_matrix)

image_stack = np.dstack(tuple(images_matrices)) 
median_array = np.median(image_stack, axis=2)

median_image = Image.fromarray(median_array)

save_image(median_image, "out.jpg")
```

When I run this code, I do get out a median image, like I want, but it is in black and white.

If I run `print image_matrix.shape` the output for my particular images is `(326, 261, 3)` but when I run `print median_array.shape` I get just `(326, 261)`.

For some reason, that part of the matrix is being cut off, resulting in a black and white image.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output image is black and white because you are taking the median over the third dimension (i.e. over the RGB channels). You need to stack your images over some dimension other than the third, for example over the fourth:

```
image_stack = np.concatenate([im[..., None] for im in image_matrices], axis=3)
```

`image_stack.shape` will then be `(326, 261, 3, nimages)`. Now you can take the median over the fourth dimension:

```
median_image = np.median(image_stack, axis=3)
```

Comment: This works, thanks!

I would like to add, that one needs to convert the image like this: `median_image = Image.fromarray(median_array.astype('uint8'))` otherwise PIL won't accept the data type.